# how find two consecutive days late comer employee in oracle PL SQL

Tags: oracle, date-arithmetic

My main table contains clock-in is TAD_REGISTER_VIEW. 
The table is massive so I just pick one specific employee with id 004634 and showing its records.

```
my table data is 

1   004634  9/1/2017    9/1/2017 9:17:00 AM 
2   004634  9/2/2017    9/2/2017 9:17:00 AM 
3   004634  9/3/2017        
4   004634  9/4/2017    9/4/2017 9:17:00 AM 
5   004634  9/5/2017    9/5/2017 9:13:00 AM 
6   004634  9/6/2017    9/6/2017 9:17:00 AM 
7   004634  9/7/2017    9/7/2017 9:17:00 AM 
8   004634  9/8/2017    9/8/2017 9:24:00 AM 
9   004634  9/9/2017    9/9/2017 9:00:00 AM 
10  004634  9/10/2017       
11  004634  9/11/2017   9/11/2017 9:04:00 AM    
12  004634  9/12/2017   9/12/2017 9:12:00 AM    
13  004634  9/13/2017   9/13/2017 10:45:00 AM   
14  004634  9/14/2017   9/14/2017 11:12:00 AM   
15  004634  9/15/2017   9/15/2017 9:12:00 AM
```

I create this query it finds all late time records after 9:15 AM. 15 minutes is a grace period. After 15 minutes he consider late comer 
My query is

```
SELECT AR.EMPLOYEEID,
           UPPER(AR.ATTENDANCETYPE) Att,
           AR.CLOCKIN,
           TO_CHAR(AR.ATTENDANCEDATE, 'dd-MON-yy') Day
      FROM TAD_REGISTER_VIEW  AR,
           EMPMASTERINFO      VEI,
           SEC_EMPLOYEES      S,
           TAD_CALENDARDETAIL D
     WHERE S.USERID = 'AFZAL'
       AND S.MISFLAG = 1
       AND AR.ATTENDANCEDATE BETWEEN '01-Sep-17' AND '30-Sep-17'
       AND AR.EMPLOYEEID = VEI.EMPLOYEEID
       AND AR.APPLICATIONID IS NULL
       AND AR.CALENDARID = D.CALENDARID
       AND S.EMPLOYEEID = VEI.EMPLOYEEID
       AND AR.ATTENDANCETYPE = 'P'
       AND AR.EMPLOYEEID= 004634    
       AND TRIM(TO_CHAR(AR.ATTENDANCEDATE, 'Day')) = TRIM(D.DAY)
       AND TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(AR.CLOCKIN, 'fmHH:MI:SS AM'),
                   'fmHH:MI:SS AM') >=
           TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(D.CLOCK_IN + 16 / 1440, 'fmHH:MI:SS AM'),
                   'fmHH:MI:SS AM')
     ORDER BY AR.PATH, AR.EMPLOYEEID, AR.ATTENDANCEDATE;
```

My result from this query for late employee is

```
1   004634  P   9/1/2017 9:17:00 AM     01-SEP-17
2   004634  P   9/2/2017 9:17:00 AM     02-SEP-17
3   004634  P   9/4/2017 9:17:00 AM     04-SEP-17
4   004634  P   9/6/2017 9:17:00 AM     06-SEP-17
5   004634  P   9/7/2017 9:17:00 AM     07-SEP-17
6   004634  P   9/8/2017 9:24:00 AM     08-SEP-17
7   004634  P   9/13/2017 10:45:00 AM   13-SEP-17
8   004634  P   9/14/2017 11:12:00 AM   14-SEP-17
```

i want 1 result for two Consecutive late day 
such as

```
2   004634  P   9/2/2017 9:17:00 AM     02-SEP-17
5   004634  P   9/7/2017 9:17:00 AM     07-SEP-17
7   004634  P   9/13/2017 10:45:00 AM   13-SEP-17
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `LAG` function to get the previous  day and compare it with `DATE -1`. Note however that the output you have shown does not say anything about 3 consecutive days(6,7,8) which has 2 consecutive day groups. Even this will be returned from this query.

```
    WITH late_employees as 
        (
        SELECT AR.EMPLOYEEID,
                   UPPER(AR.ATTENDANCETYPE) Att,
                   AR.CLOCKIN CLOCKIN,
                   AR.ATTENDANCEDATE ATTENDANCEDATE
              FROM TAD_REGISTER_VIEW  AR,
                   EMPMASTERINFO      VEI,
                   SEC_EMPLOYEES      S,
                   TAD_CALENDARDETAIL D
             WHERE S.USERID = 'AFZAL'
               AND S.MISFLAG = 1
               AND AR.ATTENDANCEDATE BETWEEN '01-Sep-17' AND '30-Sep-17'
               AND AR.EMPLOYEEID = VEI.EMPLOYEEID
               AND AR.APPLICATIONID IS NULL
               AND AR.CALENDARID = D.CALENDARID
               AND S.EMPLOYEEID = VEI.EMPLOYEEID
               AND AR.ATTENDANCETYPE = 'P'
               AND AR.EMPLOYEEID= 004634    
               AND TRIM(TO_CHAR(AR.ATTENDANCEDATE, 'Day')) = TRIM(D.DAY)
               AND TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(AR.CLOCKIN, 'fmHH:MI:SS AM'),
                           'fmHH:MI:SS AM') >=
                   TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(D.CLOCK_IN + 16 / 1440, 'fmHH:MI:SS AM'),
                           'fmHH:MI:SS AM')
                           )
        SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID,
  att,
  clockin,
  DAY
FROM
  (SELECT l.EMPLOYEE_ID ,
    l.att,
    l.clockin,
    TO_CHAR(l.ATTENDANCEDATE, 'dd-MON-yy') DAY,
    CASE
      WHEN TRUNC(LAG(l.ATTENDANCEDATE,1) OVER (ORDER BY l.ATTENDANCEDATE)) = TRUNC(l.ATTENDANCEDATE) - 1
      THEN 1
    END consec_late
  FROM late_employees l
  )
WHERE consec_late = 1;
```

**Output:**

```
4634    P   9/2/2017 9:17:00 AM     02-09-17    
4634    P   9/7/2017 9:17:00 AM     07-09-17    
4634    P   9/8/2017 9:24:00 AM     08-09-17    
4634    P   9/14/2017 11:12:00 AM   14-09-17
```

Comment: Working on LEAD LAG function will update you shortly. thanks for the help